# Controlar CheckBox en DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, checkbox, datagridview

Tengo un **DataGridView** poblado con datos traídos de **SQLServer**:

```
public void llenarId(){
        try{
            string cadena = "cadena";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cadena)){
                con.Open();
                string query = "SELECT id FROM clientes GROUP BY id";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                dtgId.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex){
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Le añadí los **CheckBox:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        llenarId();
        //dtgId.ReadOnly = true;
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        chk.HeaderText = "Seleccione";
        chk.Name = "check";
        dtgId.Columns.Add(chk);
    }
```

¿Cómo hago para que me almacene el o los **celulares**? Es decir, por cada **CheckBox** seleccionado, quiero que se almacene en una variable o en un ciclo cada **celular.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recorre el datagrid y se crea una lista con los numeros de celulares.

```
 List<string> celulares = new List<string>();
 string cel;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[6].Value.Equals(true))//Columna de checks
            {
                celulares.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());//columna donde estan los celulares
                cel = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()//variable con el celular
            }
        }
```

Esto te crea una lista en base a la columna que tiene el check seleccionado o te los obtiene uno a la vez en la variable cel